# How can I fix this problem I'm getting when I try to install firebase on Android using termux?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, npm-install, termux

Trying to install firebase on my Android using termux but I'm getting this error.

```bash
~ $ npm install -g firebase
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall link
npm ERR! path /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_cacache/tmp/23cecbe7
npm ERR! dest /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/a4/3d/598b266209821efebe25e609909ad2caceed2b3f8a7b74a75da07d88c6a9c4801e9e995ddb32695d72d767abfce727bd9a38c3a5470372fffa175a6f9e93
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 10121:10121 "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-11-11T18_19_15_987Z-debug-0.log
~ $
```

I have already installed node js.Ok

I input in the command npm install -g firebase but I got the same error.

Then I tried npm install -g firebase-tools. I still got the same error.

Comment: What's your nodejs version?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried suggested command `sudo chown -R 10121:10121 "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm"`?
Also, check if termux install from F-Droid. The Google Play version is not updating now.

Comment: sudo won't work in termux unless you are rooted. (Which is not in most cases)